# NSLog shows no output in Xcode 4.3

Tags: xcode, debugging, gdb, nslog, lldb

NSLog is giving me absolutely no console output in 4.3 all of a sudden. I've seen suggestions to switch the debugger from LLDB to GDB.

Unfortunately, GDB shows some output, but still doesn't show output from NSLog.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you are showing the output pane within the debug window (using the middle or right selection)?

Comment: Yes, I am. I've tried to view it through the log navigator as well.

Comment: Obvious suggestion, but: have you tried quitting Xcode and relaunching it?

Comment: I have tried relaunching, rebooting, and clearing the build directory.

Comment: Did you ever figure out what was going on?